# WIX: how to change license agreement during installation

Tags: licensing, wix, wix3.5

I have a requirement where by I need to show the license agreement according to the OS language. The localized license agreements (.rtf) are kept on a server.

I have created a custom action to detect OS language and download the respective license agreement, but how can I show the localized license agreement in the license agreement dialog?

I have all the dialog set files (.wxs) . I am using `Wix_Minimal` dialog set.

I tried changing the following lines in `WelcomeEulaDlg.wxs`

```
<Control Id="LicenseText" Type="ScrollableText" X="130" Y="36" Width="226" Height="162" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no">
   <Text SourceFile="!(wix.WixUILicenseRtf=$(var.licenseRtf))" />
</Control>
```

to

```
<Control Id="LicenseText" Type="ScrollableText" X="130" Y="36" Width="226" Height="162" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no" Text="[MyPropertyConatingRTFData]">
</Control>
```

but, nothing shows up in the license agreement text.

How can I set this text?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But I can think of a hack: put a GUID as the text; when license dialog displays, schedule a custom action which finds the [edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371540.aspx) and feeds the RTF you downloaded into it. This approach is not reliable but you can try it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the license agreement is only a file at build time - once the MSI is built the RTF is embedded in text format as a value in the `Control` table. (You can view this using Orca)

What this means is that in order to update this control dynamically, your custom action(s) will need to do the following:

- Download the RTF file
- Read the RTF into a string variable
- Replace the value in the relevant MSI table with something like this:

  - `'UPDATE Control SET Text='" & sRTFText & "' WHERE Dialog_='LicenseAgreementDlg' AND Control='LicenseText'`

An easier solution would be to include all languages in the same RTF file :)

Comment: Hmm, according to MSDN, "custom actions cannot modify persistent data in a database": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370519.aspx... so point #3 won't work

Comment: I tried viewing a sample msi in orca but in the text property in licenseagreement control was empty

Answer (score -1):

You can have a session variable say `LOCLICENSEFILEPATH` which will contain the path to License file based upon localization. So in the Control you simply need to pass this variable.

```
<Control Id="AgreementText" Type="ScrollableText" X="20" Y="60" Width="330" Height="140" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no">
    <Text SourceFile="[LOCLICENSEFILEPATH]" />
</Control>
```

Comment: When I compile, I get  `[LOCLICENSEFILEPATH]` not found

Comment: You must define the variable `LOCLICENSEFILEPATH` first.


Example : `<Property Id="LOCLICENSEFILEPATH" Value="Licenses\Text.rtf"/>`